# Expectation in Bayes rule

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, statistical-inference

> Let $L(\theta,\delta)=(\theta-\delta
> )^2e^{\frac{(\theta-100)^2}{900}}$ with
>   $X\sim N(\theta,100)$ and $\theta\sim N(100,225)$ find the bayes rule.

I already founded that posterior is $f(\theta|x)\sim N(\frac{9x+400}{13},\frac{900}{13})$

Then I need to calculate

$$\delta^\pi (x)=\frac{E^{f(\theta|x)}[w(\theta)g(\theta]}{E^{f(\theta|x)}[w(\theta)]}$$

where $w(\theta)=e^{\frac{(\theta-100)^2}{900}}$. Thus

$$E^{f(\theta|x)}[w(\theta)g(\theta)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \theta e^{\frac{(\theta-100)^2}{900}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2*900/13}}(\theta-\frac{9x+400}
{13})^2d\theta$$

and

$$E^{f(\theta|x)}[w(\theta)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{\frac{(\theta-100)^2}{900}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2*900/13}}(\theta-\frac{9x+400}
{13})^2d\theta$$

probably should be some simplification, but I could not do.

Comment: Where do you use $\delta$ from the first line?

Comment: Is a typo replace a for delta